# How to blend a 2D terrain

Tags: unity, 2d, terrain, blending, top-down

[image]

Rimworld (shown above) has many different terrain types.

In order to achieve Rimworld styled terrain, I need to achieve two goals

A) How to render differently textured terrains

B) How to blend these terrains (which is what this question is about)

Demonstrated below as an example ( think each square as different terrain type)

[image]

I can easily solve A by rendering a mesh that, say, represent, stone terrain and render another mesh representing grass terrain.

[image]

However this is not enough because the sections in which two different terrain types meet must be blended

[image]

There are many ways I can think of to achieve this however all methods that I can think of are not fitting to render a giant 2d map (look at the first picture)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some basics: in this case linear interpolation (and its limitations), using pure colours. Once you're on the right track, you can figure things out from there.

First, try to recreate the below image using [`Mathf.Lerp()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html), to create a controlled 1D interpolation between two adjacent colours:

[image]

(expanded vertically so you can see it more clearly)

[image]

Next, try to `Lerp()` in 2D, also known as [`bilerp()`](https://forum.unity.com/threads/bi-lerp.175105/) to create an interpolation on a quadrilateral with 4 colours, one at each of the corners of the quad:

[image]

(You can see that bilinear interpolation specifically operates on quads.)

You can see here how the final result comes out between (grid-aligned) world tiles / chunks, with the 2D / bilerped example above, being the middle tile between 4 pure colour tiles:

[image]

The easiest way to create the above in Unity is to set up a textured quad facing the camera, then use [`Texture2D.setPixel()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html) to build a texture according to the numbers you get out of your linear interpolation functions given above.

Once implemented on the CPU using Unity's `Lerp()` & custom `Bilerp()`, you can then shift this logic over to `lerp()` textures correctly on the GPU if desired.

**EDIT per comments** How your input map must look to be blended this way (grid-aligned cells):

[image]

Comment: Go through the proper process of learning, and you will save much more time down the line than you would trying to hack your way to a solution (never mind maintaining that solution). You will likely also end up with far better visual results.

Comment: I'd recommend encoding the colours of just the corners of the grid in the texture's pixels, like a conventional 3D terrain splatmap, and letting the GPU texture sampler's bilinear filtering handle the bilerp for you. That saves texture memory/bandwidth, CPU cycles, and it's less code to write too.  Then you can use that interpolated splatmap to blend 4 (or even 5) tiling terrain textures in the shader.

Comment: @DMGregory Correct - that would be the final goal for the OP, but keeping things simple to start with. A basic understanding of terrain blending is hopefully clear from the above.

Comment: @Engineer Thanks for the answer. This has a few issues. Approaching this like you do splatmap makes rendering process way too heavy; because there are many terrain types.  There could be 10-or more ground(Terrain) types, and I would need to sample 10 times for each pixel to get the right color. Also each terrain type is likely to require a different shader. If I were to render this in a single go, I need a master shader that does a complicated process to render many different effects for each different terrain type.

Comment: I found https://forum.unity.com/threads/megasplat-256-textures-in-one-splat-map-shader.437638/ this, they have splat map with 256 textures... I am wondering how such is possible

Comment: Ok I think they used an int as a way to determine which texture to use. So I am thinking, maybe each vertex cotains two int(two textures) to determine whether it needs to blend two texture or just rendering one. So that means, each vertex contains two int and two float to denote two textures and alpha value of each texture?

Comment: Ok now I realized the maximum number which a vertex can be surrounded by different vertexs is 4 (up down left and right) so I MUST sample 4 times for each pixel. So my shader will have 4 ints to denote texture ID and 4 floats to denote alpha values in which these 4 textures should blend!

Comment: @BlueBug I think you're starting to get the idea. If you quantise your original map into a grid of however many different colours, you will only ever have a maximum of 4 colours at any individual vertex. Then you can do bilerp in software, or use GPU texture filtering to do the work for you. Good luck!

Comment: @Engineer however this means each terrain type having a different shading method is impossible because its basically a splatmap... right?

Comment: I guess for my Soil, I could render just default Soil on splat map, then bring another shader and do another geometry with soil effects then put that geometry over my splat map?

Comment: @BlueBug If I understand correctly, I think you will need multiple passes to achieve a shading method per material. You can change the vertex interpolation information per pass.

Comment: @BlueBug I've added an image to the end of the answer so that we are on the same page in regards to how you would handle your original map. The resolution is not important; it can be very high (max texture size) but what matters is that your input buffer of "terrain types" - which could indeed be represented as simple colours / IDs in a byte buffer - are _grid-aligned_. You may need to modify how the game logic works, to achieve that. But in this way, you will get the fastest possible blending basis. Note how the colours fall exactly along grid lines.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about a solution

[image]

If there was a terrain such as above example, dirt should be below grass.

I could render dirt terrain to overlap grass terrains a little (below)

[image]

Then render Grass mesh on top of dirt terrain, then have its edges be rendered with transparency

[image]

However I still need to solve needing to apply different transparent value at the edges.

I wonder if I were to select this method, should each vertices contain "transparency value"? so that vertex at the edge contains zero-or-low transparency value